# How to use awk/sed to replace data in a specific column in certain rows only

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have a space-delimited text file where the bulk of the rows look like this:

```
--- 23:123456_A_B 123456 A B [and ~600K more columns after that]
```

However, there are some rows where the first 5 columns look like this:

```
23 . 234567 C D
```

Can anyone suggest an awk or sed command (or any alternative method) that would change the first column from `23` to `---` and the second column from `.` to `23:234567_C_D` (using the data from the first five columns) while leaving the other columns untouched, but only in those rows that start with `23`?

Comment: What you ask is trivial to do with sed or awk but the devil in the details,e.g. do you need the space between fields to remain as-is or just the fields? Post 5 or so lines of sample input and expected output, with just 5 or so fields on each line.

Comment: How long is each 'line' in this file?  You say 600K columns, each with a space and at least 1 other character, so that's 1.2 MiB per row?  Wow!!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the field separator is just a single space,

```
sed -r 's/^23 \. ([^ ]+) ([^ ]+) ([^ ]+)/--- 23:\1_\2_\3 \1 \2 \3/' file
```

More readable with awk

```
awk '$1 == 23 && $2 == "." {$1 = "---"; $2 = "23:" $3 "_" $4 "_" $5} 1' file
```

With sed, you can save the changes in-place with the `-i` option.
With awk, you may have to explicitly write to a temp file:

```
tmp=$(mktemp)
awk '....' file > "$tmp" && mv "$tmp" file
```

Comment: Thanks everyone, both the awk and the sed commands worked great. really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```
$ cat file
--- 23:123456_A_B 123456 A B [and ~600K more columns after that]
23 . 234567 C D

$ awk '$1==23 { $2=$1":"$3"_"$4"_"$5; $1="---" }1' file
--- 23:123456_A_B 123456 A B [and ~600K more columns after that]
--- 23:234567_C_D 234567 C D
```